# Keep mplayer open after video playback

Tags: linux, command-line, mplayer

Is it possible to make mplayer freeze in the last frame of the video instead of closing?

I am using CLI version of mplayer in linux.

Comment: I have the same problem and use a bright `xterm` and the `dwm` window manager. My wife is always annoyed by the bright screen at the end of a longer movie. Starting a bounty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this

```
#mplayer test.ogg -idle -fixed-vo
```

Comment: awesome, you are my hero. Note: This also works for the `vdpau` video output, although the manpage states only `gl,  gl2, mga, svga, x11, xmga, xv, xvidix and dfbmga`

Comment: here, it seems that, while the video **does** freeze at the last frame, the time controls (going back) do not work.
Is it supposed to be like that ? Any way around it ?

Comment: why no UI for this????

Comment: For mpv (not sure about mplayer), one can also use `-keep-open` - that enables you to seek back as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with mplayer's slave mode. See:
http://www1.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt

Also mentioned in the FAQ, 5th question under *General Questions*:
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPlayer_FAQ#General_Questions

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also found the `-slave` and `-idle` options. The do prevent `mplayer` from exiting, however, they always *close* the video window. In my case, the bright `xterm` appears. Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't have my Linux laptop handy so can't try at the moment, but I really believe its how I had it going in slavemode. A few guesses that I might have used is **-fs** for fullscreen, and maybe **show_videowin** set to yes in gui.conf? Hope some of those makes a difference. Another "ugly" workaround is to use the -loop option to just loop the movie a bunch of times, but that might be even more annoying. ;)

Comment: `-fs` does not work unfortunately. `show_videowin` does not apply to me, as I don't use the *gui* version.

Answer (score -2):

The feature you need can be supproted by adding new fscommands in a revised version.
But the pause-on-last-frame feature will only work in wmp6.X rather than on 7.X.(Add the fscommand "fas.avclip.USEWMP6" to force utilize V6.X)

Comment: Can you clarify for me what you mean by "fscommands" and "revised version"?

Comment: I think `wmp6` is related to actionscript/flash and not to `mplayer`.